# How to get data from database with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

Using c#, net.4.5 vs 2012

I'm trying to get data from database using Entity Framework.

At first idea was use code like below - it's must allow to add, delete and update entries in dataGridView, and than just save changes using `context.SaveChanges()` (method from `ObjectSet`, if I'm not wrong)

```
using (LibraryEntities context = new LibraryEntities())
{
            var query = (from c in context.Book select c).First();
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            dgv.DataSource = context.Book;
}
```

Result - exception

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported...

Then I try a little bit changed code:

```
using (LibraryEntities context = new LibraryEntities())
{
    var query = (from c in context.Book select c).First();
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.DataSource = query;
}
```

but have same issue with exception

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported...

At last try to convert all to `List()`:

```
using (LibraryLib.LibraryEntities context = new LibraryLib.LibraryEntities())
{
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.DataSource = (from c in context.Book select c).ToList();
}
```

As and expected, I got all db entries in DataGridView, but I can't add, update and delete any entries.

[image]

And the question is - how can I change db in `dataGridView` and than save it with `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk, SO is an english only site.  Google offer's this as a translation `Hey. Try to consider the ready examples are not quite understand everything`

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks, I know - it's because of rare case of seeing Ukrainian people here ;)

Comment: @Elliot Tereschuk Привіт, а що саме нечітко описано? / HI, what not correctly described in question?

Comment: @Elliot Tereschuk. так, але коли я приводжу до колекції, я отримую результат. проблема в тому. що я не можу видалити або додати запис до `DataGridView` В останньому варіанті - все добре працює. Що хочу я - пернести всю базу даних до `DataGridView`. редагувати її (видаляти міняти значення додавати рядки. тощо). А потім повністю зберегти. Як це зробити?, адже спробувавши так як описано в книжці - видає виключення.

Comment: @Elliot Tereschuk. Yep, but when i'll try to get collection  - all works, but i cant do   anything in `DataGridView`. what I want - it's to load all db in `DataGridView` than modify its entities and change them (mean add, del or update) and than just save it using `DbContext.SaveChanges()` - like described in mny of tutorials that i seen - but i cant due to existing of exception

Comment: @Kirill Радий, що рішення знайшлось. [Додавайтесь у друзі](http://vk.com/ilyatereschuk)

Comment: @Elliot Tereschuk нажаль не зараєстрований там, проте можеш додати в скайпі - kirill.g3, буду вдячний за допомогу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it winforms?
 if yes, you have to use BindingSource to link data

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = typeof(Book); // Book is a type of your Entity class

        db.Book.ToList().ForEach(n => bs.Add(n)); 
        dgv.DataSource = bs;
```

now it's editable. And 
to store changes just call db.SaveChanges();

your way to assing List to DataGrid is valid for WPF. What about to migrate there?

Comment: Yep, i use WinForms, I'm thinking about wpf, but currently i'm just studing (in free from work time) c#. First of all try to understand main milestones. Your proposal perfect - as I understand I must to add some "buffer" for data before use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use repository pattern with unitofwork pattern which means a repository class which will handle all CRUD operations and unit of work class to commit all the changes together.

Comment: Can you provide any link for getting some tutorial or additional information regarding this pattern, if be honestly - never hear about this

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37155/Implementing-Repository-Pattern-With-Entity-Framew     For Unitofwork - create T4 template